# How to make a gem support multiple Ruby versions elegantly

Tags: ruby, version

I'm writing a gem that I want to work across multiple Ruby versions, what's the best way to do this?  The naive solution is to do stuff like this

```
if RUBY_VERSION <= 1.8.7
   my_hash = {:a => 1}
elsif RUBY_VERSION >= 1.9.3
   my_hash = {a: 1}
...
end
```

What's the best way to make your gem support multiple Ruby versions?

Comment: Hashrockets will always be supported for Hashes unless someone wants to limit keys to a limited set of symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write two versions of gems on different files within the `lib` directory, and on the main file, load either of them depending on the Ruby version.

**Main file (foo_gem/lib/foo.rb)**

```
if RUBY_VERSION <= 1.8.7
  require_relative "./foo-ruby1.8.7"
elsif RUBY_VERSION >= 1.9.3
  require_relative "./foo-ruby1.9.3"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby > 1.9.3 still supports the old hash syntax. If you need to support 1.8.7 and your only problem are hash literals, the elegant solution is to use the old syntax exclusively. This way you can drop any conditionals.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  The hash syntax was just an example (and maybe a bad one), but suppose its for some piece of code where that isn't forward compatible.  That is, it works for 1.8.7 but not 2.0.0.

Comment: Then I would try to encapsulate the incompatible part inside a method and nest that method definition inside the conditional. That way, you can abstract away the inconsistency in the API and just pretend that everything is working. You might also find the backports gem useful https://rubygems.org/gems/backports